# jupyter notebook slow at responding to updates in code or text information

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

So I have a project that has multiple files regular python, and I'm using a jupyter lab python file as the 'main' file that imports and runs all the rest of the code. But if I make changes to those python files, the jupyter lab file does not automatically respond to updates in those files, and it takes a long time before the code runs properly with the updates.

The main problem is that I have a text file that I constantly update, and the jupyter lab file reads from that, but it takes forever before the changes in the text file are actually noticed and the code runs off that. Is this just a known issue with jupyter lab or?

Comment: Do you use auto-import IPython magic? This question is very unclear, there is no function of "automatically responding" enabled by default so please describe exactly what your setup is and provide a minimum reproducible example of the performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code so is difficult to know what is happening here. But how the Jupyter environ "notice" these changes? You must to re run de code again and must to consider than Jupyter  maintain the vars in memory until the kernel is restarted (because the garbage collector of Python).

I've tried to erase the variables with `del` but always Jupyter maintain a reference to the old value (I don't know why) for that reason I try to use my code inside of function's scope in this way the variable dies when the function is done. This is the only way I found to deal with this problem.

I always try work with functions because is hard to debug a code in Jupyter with old variables values.